# Google Spreadsheet: SUM(FILTER( with condition1 and condition2) syntax?

Tags: google-sheets

I need to use FILTER() to sum some cells only if two conditions are TRUE.
This code works for one condition `=sum(filter(H4:H, regexmatch(G4:G, "TextA"))`  but I can't get it to work on two condition:`=sum(filter(H4:H, regexmatch(I4:I, "TextA") + regexmathch(J4:J, "TextB")))`

My code should sum all the cells from H(starting in H4) only if in the row, this cell, the column I and J contain TextA and TextB respectively.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to use FILTER(), this looks like the perfect case for SUMIFS().

```
=sumifs(H1:H6, I1:I6, "TextA", J1:J6, "TextB")
```

[image]

Comment: Any idea what are the performance differences between sumifs() and sum(filter())?

Comment: I haven't tested, but an educated guess would be that sumifs() will be quicker, especially with regexp functions inside of filter()

Answer (score 1):

How about using `AND`?

```
=sum(filter(H4:H, AND(regexmatch(I4:I, "TextA"), regexmatch(J4:J, "TextB"))))
```

Also, `filter` allows for several conditions.

```
=sum(filter(H4:H, regexmatch(I4:I, "TextA"), regexmatch(J4:J, "TextB")))
```

Comment: In the past AND didn't work with arrays. Did you test it?

Comment: @Rubén I must admit that I did not.

Comment: Google made changes that make that SPLIT work with arrays, so it will be reasonable to make a try with AND